# How do I know if this will be rational or irrational? ($a^b$)

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Usually, when I have $a^b$ when $a$ and $b$ are both irrational, I assume that it will be irrational.  But that is not always true, I assume, so when is the result irrational?  How will I know?

Take something like $e^e$ or $\pi^{\pi}$ and tell me if those are irrational or rational and why.

Comment: [The Gelfond–Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem): If $a$ and $b$ are algebraic numbers with $a \not= 0,1$ and $b$ irrational, then any value of $a^b$ is a transcendental number.

Comment: @Winther Well, its a theorem, but it should work.  Could you provide me a proof?

Comment: It's a pretty high-level result so I don't know the proof. You can probably find one by searching, but it's not going to be short. Note that it only applies for algebraic $a,b$. It does not say anything about $a^b$ is when $a$ is trancendental (which $e$ and $\pi$ is).

Comment: @Winther Thanks for pointing me in this direction.  ;D

Comment: The other simple answer is that most numbers are irrational, so if $a,b$ are both irrational, $a^b$ will (almost) always be irrational unless it is constructed to be rational.  So $(\sqrt 2^{\sqrt 2})^{\sqrt 2}$ is constructed to be rational and is in fact $2$  Obviously, that is not a proof, but proving that numbers like $e^e$ are irrational is often hard.

Comment: @RossMillikan LoL, isn't that cheating, guessing it will be irrational by knowing "most" answers will come out irrational?!

Comment: No, it is not cheating.  It is not a proof in any particular case, so should not be offered as one.  You have to be honest about the basis of the claim that it is irrational, but it is still a strong claim.

Comment: For many $a,b$ it is a wide open problem whether $a^b$ is irrational or not. I'm pretty sure $\pi^e,\pi^\pi,e^e,\sqrt{2}^e$ are all examples. We know the full answer for case when $a,b$ are algebraic, per Winther's comment, but not much beyond that.

Comment: @Wojowu As a side note, do you check the "big-number" tag?

Comment: @SimpleArt No, but to be honest I didn't know such tag exists.

Comment: @Wojowu :D  Well, I hope you can answer some of the questions there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Gelfond-Schneider theorem** for this. The theorem states that:

> *If $a$ and $b$ are algebraic numbers with $a ≠ 0,1$ and $b$ non-rational, then any value of $a^b$ is a transcendental number.*

This not only gives rise to trivial results such that $2^{\sqrt 2}$ is irrational, but to some more interesting ones as well. For instance, by taking $a=-1$ and $b=-i$, where $i=\sqrt {-1}$, we can obtain the following result:

$$
(-1)^{-i} = \left( e^{i \pi} \right)^{-i} = e^\pi,
$$

showing that $e^\pi$ is transcendental.

Comment: In what sense is the irrationality of $2^{\sqrt2}$ a trivial result? Is there an elementary proof that doesn't invoke GS?